# Bootstrap CTA button full height of right column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble trying to get my right column to have a button that takes up the entire height and width of the column. Here is my code below. I've tried adjusting the heights, setting positions and still haven't found any luck in this weird structure.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 4, SCSS and jQuery as my build frameworks.

**My bootstrap code**

```css
.cta-section {
  background: #243635;
  .center-align {
    align-items: $center-align;
  }
  .section-content-left {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2.625rem 3.5rem 2.625rem 8.125rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: $h2size;
    font-family: $nunito;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: $colorwhite;
  }
  p {
    font-size: $font15px;
    color: $colorwhite;
    line-height: 1.625rem;
    opacity: .77;
  }
  .cta-block-right {
    background: $colorgreen;
    font-family: $nunito;
    color: $colorwhite;
    .cta-large {
      color: $colorwhite;
      b {
        color: $colorwhite !important;
      }
    }
  }
} // End Cta Section
```

```html
<div class="cta-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row center-align">

      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="section-content-left">
          <h2> We Make It Easy To Find Work You Love</h2>
          <p> It can seem daunting applying for a new career. Not to mention that you're interested in doing it in an innovative way (remotely). Don't worry, we have a simple process and we'll walk you through from start to finish. </p>
        </div>
        <!-- end section-content-left -->
      </div>
      <!-- col-md-8 col-sm-12 -->


      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 column-bg-green" style="
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
            ">
        <div class="cta-block-right" style="
                /* position: absolute; */
            ">
          <a class="cta-large" href="#"> <b>  See Our Process </b> </a>

        </div>
        <!-- end cta-block-right -->
      </div>
      <!-- end col-md-4 col-sm-12 -->


    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
  </div>
  <!--end container -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EXPLANATION**

In Bootstrap 4 *rows* and *col* are made using Flexbox. Therefore by default the Bootstrap *col* takes the entire height available because the default `align-item` property of it's *row* flex container's parent is "stretch".

---

**SOLUTION**

Simply remove all inline styles and add the Bootstrap CSS class `.h-100` on the `.cta-block-right` button.

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 column-bg-green">
    <div class="cta-block-right h-100">
      <a class="cta-large" href="#"> <b>  See Our Process </b> </a>
    </div>
    <!-- end cta-block-right -->
</div>
<!-- end col-md-4 col-sm-12 -->
```

That should do it :)